# Extract Columns that Do Not Exist in Another Matrix Based on Column Names

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices `df_matrix` and `df_subset`. One is a subset of the other one. Therefore, `df_matrix` has 10000 rows and columns and `df_subset` contains only 8222 columns and rows of `df_matrix`.

I want to select only those ***columns*** **from** `df_matrix` that are NOT in `df_subset`. I thought it is best to do it by column names, so I tried executing this code:

```
newdf <- df_matrix[, which( (colnames(df_matrix)) != (colnames(KroneckerProducts)) )]
```

However, this is not working at all. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Use `%in%`: `df_matrix[,!(colnames(df_matrix) %in% colnames(KroneckerProducts)) ]`

Comment: @nicola : just said the same thing :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General rule is not to use == or != with objects of different length

Use %in% with !

```
newdf <- df_matrix[, !(colnames(df_matrix) %in% colnames(KroneckerProducts))]
```